# Boot messages on both VGA and serial console

Tags: boot, console, serial

I use RHEL6 (with GRUB and upstart from Ubuntu) and want to put boot messages on my normal VGA console as well on serial port.

I got GRUB to put messages on one of them, but not on both at same time.

Any suggestions?

Comment: GRUB menu or linux boot messages? Grub [menu](http://www.iitk.ac.in/LDP/HOWTO/Remote-Serial-Console-HOWTO/configure-boot-loader-grub.html#CONFIGURE-BOOT-LOADER-GRUB-SERIALCONSOLE) seems to be possible.

Comment: Boot messages. Upstart looks in GRUB config after console and decide which is primary, only this one get then boot messages.